# how to get timezone offset of different places in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get the current time of different places using javascript.
I would get the UTC using following method.

```
function calcUTC() {
    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // subtract local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    return utc;
}
```

Now I need to find the timezoneOffset of a particular place so that i can add this offset to the utc to get the current time of the location.
The places could be US,CANADA or any other. there are three different timezones in US. kindly do the possible
Thanks

Comment: Dates and times are not trivial. You need to be a lot more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. And what it is specifically that you need.  What research have you already done? there are numerous in depth sites related to this topic. Also javascript Date object has built in UTC methods

Comment: @charlietfl–the ECMAScript Date methods are quite simple once you realise that a Date object is just a UTC [*time value*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range) and local offset.

Comment: The subject here is misleading. You seem to be asking how to get the time at a place given a timezone offset. The subject seems to ask for the opposite. Oh, and to get the UTC time (which the Date object has already) you must **add** the ECMAScript offset as it has the opposite sign to ISO offsets, e.g. ISO UTC+1000 is ECMAScript -600 (minutes).

Answer (score 3):

getTime() method of Date object itself returns UTC value.

Refer: [MDN Date object getTime Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

It says,

> Method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the
>   specified date according to universal time.

You should not need to subtract or add local time zone offset.

In order to calculate local time for other time zones, you would need to find the offset values for these time-zones (this should take into account the daylight saving time).

*Note: JavaScript Date object does not provide any method that takes time zone as input and returns offset for that timezone.*

Also, if offset value is absolute, you will need to subtract or add offset, depending upon whether the time zone is before or after GMT.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the time zone offset of the place you want the time of, it's quite simple to just use UTC methods. For example:

```
/*
** @param {number} offsetInMinutes - Timezone offset for place to be returned
**                                    +ve for east, -ve for west
*/
function timeAt(offsetInMinutes) {
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0':'') + n}
  var now = new Date();
  now.setUTCMinutes(now.getUTCMinutes() + offsetInMinutes);
  return z(now.getUTCHours()) + ':' + z(now.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + z(now.getUTCSeconds());
}
```

So for a place UTC+0200 you'd do:

```
console.log(timeAt(120));
```

and for a place UTC-0430 you'd do:

```
console.log(timeAt(-270));
```